# Formatting returned Database Objects Laravel

Tags: php, codeigniter, laravel, laravel-5

I have (finally) began working with Laravel after many years mainly developing using CI and was wondering how to ensure all of my returned database rows were returned in the same "format" so to say. For example in Codeigniter I could do the following:

```
<?php

Class Users_model extends CI_Model
{
 public $user_id;
 public $name;
 public $profile_image;
 public $status;

 const STATUS_ACTIVE   =  1;
 const STATUS_INACTIVE =  0;
 const STATUS_DELETED  = -1;


 function getById($user_id)
 {

    // typecasting
    $user_id = (int) $user_id;

    // database query
    $this->db->where('id', $user_id);
    $q = $this->db->get('users');

    // fetch the user record
    $row = $result->row();

    // set user values
    $this->user_id       = $row->id;
    $this->name          = $row->name;
    $this->profile_image = $row->image;
    $this->status        = $row->status;

    // return
    return $this;

 }

 function getListOfUsers()
 {

    // select 
    $this->db->select('id');

    // where query
    $this->db->where('status', self::STATUS_ACTIVE);

    // exectute query
    $q = $this->db->get('users');

    // get query results
    $results = $q->results();

    // set up default return
    $return = array();

    // loop through db results
    foreach($results as $r)
    {
        $u = new Users_model();
        $return[] = $u->getById($r->id);
    }

    return $return;
 }
}
?>
```

It is a small example but this class would enable me to ensure all of my calls for users from the database run through a singular function (getByID) - obviously everything is heavily cached for performance reasons. What is the best way to apply the same logic in Laravel. Obviously I could write my own model class but it seems silly to use Laravel and not make use of the Eloquent ORM. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

I tried the following:

```
<?php namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Products extends Model {

/**
 * The database table used by the model.
 *
 * @var string
 */
protected $table = 'products';

/**
* set the constants
*
*/
const TYPE_USER        = 0;
const TYPE_STYLIST     = 1;
const STATUS_INACTIVE  = 0;
const STATUS_ACTIVE    = 1;

/**
* set the cache constants
*
*/
const CACHE_KEY    = 'Product/%d';
const CACHE_LENGTH = 86400;

public $product_id;
public $store;
public $name;
public $slug;
public $url_string;

function getProduct()
{
    $this->product_id = (int) 1;
    $this->store      = (int) 23;
    $this->name       = (string) 'Nike Air Max';
    $this->slug       = (string) 'nike-air-max';
    $this->url_string = (string) 'http://asos.com';

    return $this;
}

}
?>
```

But get all of the unnecessary class information (obviously) and more importantly I don't know how I would apply this using the Eloquent functions such as

```
$users = User::all();
```

Thanks for reading

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you correctly you could do the following in Eloquent.

```
$tryThis = Your\Product\Model::find($id)
```

This would return all fields where the ID matches. More important it would return as a collection as would any other query you write using the Eloquent ORM.

Then you can just access a collection like so;

```
$tryThis->id;
```

Comment: Hi Jake, thanks for answering but I think what I am looking for is the data mutation methods you can add to models :)

Comment: [http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-mutators](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-mutators) - does that help at all? It depends on what you are wanting to do with your data.

Comment: Yeah thats exactly what I was looking for :) I'm pretty sure I can do everything I need using these classes. Do you know if you can add nodes to the object using these?